# Excel VBA will not loop through worksheets (Exclude Worksheet)

Tags: vba, excel

The macro appears to loops through all of the worksheets fine now.  However, is there a way that I can make it so the macro does not get applied to a specific worksheet in my workbook, but does get applied to all other worksheets?

```
Sub FormatSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
        Columns("A:J").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 1
        End With
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Try doing 'Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count' to make sure there is more than one worksheet. 'ThisWorkbook' refers to the workbook that the code is in, not the activeworkbook.

Comment: So this got me thinking and I changed ThisWorkbook.Worksheets to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets in the code and it seems to run fine now.  Thanks!

Comment: Did that fix the problem? Keep in mind though that ActiveWorkbook and ActiveWorksheet (as well as Activate, Select, Selection) should all be avoided where possible (and rarely is there a case where you can't replace these items with a more robust solution). If you are just doing this as a temporary thing then that's fine, but if youre going to be using this macro in a more consistent sense I would recommend learning how to avoid the above noted items.

Comment: I'm curious what the selection.autofilter does?  Does it just add dropdown lists on the top row?

Comment: Brandon - Yes, that seemed to fix the problem... This is just a fragment of a macro that I will be using on a monthly basis. I'll certainly have to learn more in order to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: John - yeah, it simply applies a filter to the selected columns

Answer (score 0):

I created a dataset to test this out and found that the code worked just fine.  So it must be something related to your specific data/worksheets.  I would see if 2 sheets works, or try making a smaller sample on another workbook and see if it works.  Sorry I'm not more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                .Resize(.Rows.Count-1).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```